# Rails 3: Find parent of polymorphic model in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, polymorphic-associations

I'm trying to find an elegant (standard) way to pass the parent of a polymorphic model on to the view. For example:

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, :as => :imageable
end 

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, :as => :imageable
end
```

The following way (`find_imageable`) works, but it seems "hackish".

#### #PictureController (updated to include full listing)

```
class PictureController < ApplicationController
  #/employees/:id/picture/new
  #/products/:id/picture/new
  def new
    @picture = imageable.pictures.new
    respond_with [imageable, @picture]
  end

  private
  def imageable
    @imageable ||= find_imageable
  end

  def find_imageable 
    params.each do |name, value|
      if name =~ /(.+)_id$/  
        return $1.classify.constantize.find(value)  
      end  
    end  
    nil
  end
end
```

Is there a better way?

**EDIT**

I'm doing a `new` action. The path takes the form of `parent_model/:id/picture/new` and params include the parent id (`employee_id` or `product_id`).

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do but if you're trying to find the object that 'owns' the picture you should be able to use the imageable_type field to get the class name. You don't even need a helper method for this, just

```
def show
  @picture = Picture.find(params[:id])
  @parent = @picture.imagable
  #=> so on and so forth
end
```

**Update**
For an index action you could do

```
def index
  @pictures = Picture.includes(:imagable).all
end
```

That will instantiate all 'imagables' for you.

**Update II: The Wrath of Poly**
For your new method you could just pass the id to your constructor, but if you want to instantiate the parent you could get it from the url like

```
def parent
  @parent ||= %w(employee product).find {|p| request.path.split('/').include? p }
end

def parent_class
  parent.classify.constantize
end

def imageable
  @imageable ||= parent_class.find(params["#{parent}_id"])
end
```

You could of course define a constant in your controller that contained the possible parents and use that instead of listing them in the method explicitly. Using the request path object feels a little more 'Rails-y' to me.

Comment: If you really want to do the find just do `@picture.imagable_type.find(value)`

Comment: @dogenpunk what's the difference between `Picture.all` and `Picture.includes(:imageable).all` if Picture must be associated with one of the other models?

Comment: includes(:imageable) eager loads the object referenced by the imagable association.

Comment: Unless your users are actually updating the parent class from this action, I don't see the need to instantiate the parent class. You're just adding an unnecessary db call as you have the needed data from the request object to instantiate a new @picture.

Comment: pretty much the same thing ... now we're extracting name from the url rather than the passed parameter. I was hoping there was a `params[:parent_model]` field since you're coming here from the parent anyways. P.S. I goofed up in the links (`employee**s**/:id/`); modifies your code to `...include p.pluralize }` . Thanks for the help. I think I'll post this in rails google group.

Comment: woops just your comment ... I'm displaying some data from the parent class; hence the db call is important. If you see the new method, I pass both objects to the view

Comment: Well, you could checkout the resource_controller gem. It gives you similar functionality and then some. https://github.com/jamesgolick/resource_controller

Comment: After using includes(:imageable) to load the object referenced y the imagable association in the index action, how do you get that imageable object's attributes in the view?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this same problem.

The way I 'sort of' solved it is defining a find_parent method in each model with polymorphic associations.

```
class Polymorphic1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent1, :polymorphic => true
  def find_parent
    self.parent1
  end
end

class Polymorphic2 < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent2, :polymorphic => true
  def find_parent
    self.parent2
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, I can not think of a better way. Hope this helps a bit for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I did it for multiple nested resources, where the last param is the polymorphic model we are dealing with: (only slightly different from your own)

```
def find_noteable
  @possibilities = []
  params.each do |name, value|
    if name =~ /(.+)_id$/  
      @possibilities.push $1.classify.constantize.find(value)
    end
  end
  return @possibilities.last
end
```

Then in the view, something like this:

```
<% # Don't think this was needed: @possibilities << picture %>
<%= link_to polymorphic_path(@possibilities.map {|p| p}) do %>
```

The reason for returning the last of that array is to allow finding the child/poly records in question i.e. @employee.pictures or @product.pictures